# emacs not applying my configuration on startup

Tags: emacs

im new to emacs and im currently setting up the line number in my ~/.emacs.d/init.el file, like this :

`(setq display-line-numbers 'relative)`

and the whole init.el looks like this :

```
(setq display-line-numbers 'relative)
;; set up melpa
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
    '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

;; set packages
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)

(require 'doom-modeline)
(doom-modeline-mode 1)

(require 'sublimity)
;; (require 'sublimity-scroll)
;; (require 'sublimity-map) ;; experimental
;; (require 'sublimity-attractive)
(sublimity-mode 1)

;; (require 'smooth-scrolling)
;; (smooth-scrolling-mode 1)



;;system set values
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-faces-vector
   [default bold shadow italic underline bold bold-italic bold])
 '(ansi-color-names-vector
   ["#454545" "#cd5542" "#6aaf50" "#baba36" "#5180b3" "#ab75c3" "#68a5e9" "#bdbdb3"])
 '(beacon-color "#cc6666")
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (atom-one-dark)))
 '(custom-safe-themes
   (quote
    ("d1af5ef9b24d25f50f00d455bd51c1d586ede1949c5d2863bef763c60ddf703a" "36ca8f60565af20ef4f30783aa16a26d96c02df7b4e54e9900a5138fb33808da" "c9ddf33b383e74dac7690255dd2c3dfa1961a8e8a1d20e401c6572febef61045" "06f0b439b62164c6f8f84fdda32b62fb50b6d00e8b01c2208e55543a6337433a" "628278136f88aa1a151bb2d6c8a86bf2b7631fbea5f0f76cba2a0079cd910f7d" "82d2cac368ccdec2fcc7573f24c3f79654b78bf133096f9b40c20d97ec1d8016" default)))
 '(fci-rule-color "#373b41")
 '(flycheck-color-mode-line-face-to-color (quote mode-line-buffer-id))
 '(frame-background-mode (quote dark))
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (sublimity atom-one-dark-theme ample-theme color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow doom-modeline vterm evil undo-tree)))
 '(vc-annotate-background nil)
 '(vc-annotate-color-map
   (quote
    ((20 . "#cc6666")
     (40 . "#de935f")
     (60 . "#f0c674")
     (80 . "#b5bd68")
     (100 . "#8abeb7")
     (120 . "#81a2be")
     (140 . "#b294bb")
     (160 . "#cc6666")
     (180 . "#de935f")
     (200 . "#f0c674")
     (220 . "#b5bd68")
     (240 . "#8abeb7")
     (260 . "#81a2be")
     (280 . "#b294bb")
     (300 . "#cc6666")
     (320 . "#de935f")
     (340 . "#f0c674")
     (360 . "#b5bd68"))))
 '(vc-annotate-very-old-color nil)
 '(vterm-kill-buffer-on-exit t)
 '(window-divider-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )


;; bindings
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-a") 'evil-normal-state) 

;; addition customization
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
;; scroll one line at a time (less "jumpy" than defaults)
(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 1))) ;; one line at a time
(setq mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil) ;; don't accelerate scrolling
(setq mouse-wheel-follow-mouse 't) ;; scroll window under mouse
(setq scroll-step 1) ;; keyboard scroll one line at a time


;; set evil-mode delete always goes to black hole register
(defun bb/evil-delete (orig-fn beg end &optional type _ &rest args)
  (apply orig-fn beg end type ?_ args))
(advice-add 'evil-delete :around 'bb/evil-delete)
```

the problem is that emacs doesn't show the relative line number when startup, which i demanded on the first line of init.el, but if i use `M-x load-file <RET> ~/.emacs.d/init.el <RET>` it than showed the line number as i wanted.

i also checked the *user-init-file* in *described-variable(C-h v)* and it showed `user-init-file is a variable defined in ‘C source code’. Its value is "/Users/<USER>/.emacs.d/init.el"`. So im totally confused on why can't emacs display the line number automatically on startup when it seems to be loaded.

im using macos with macport emacs, and im not using any emacs distros.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is buffer-local, i.e. when you enable it, it becomes enabled only in the current buffer, which is probably not the buffer visiting the current file.

Use customization to enable the variable globally. When you run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`describe-variable` `display-line-numbers`, the help text will contain a link to customization. You can select the *Relative* value and save the value for future sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this?

```el
(setq-default display-line-numbers 'relative)
(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `display-line-numbers-type` instead of `display-line-numbers`.

From it's documentation:

> Documentation: The default type of line numbers to use in
> ‘display-line-numbers-mode’.